# Does NIC Teaming in Windows increase bandwidth in case of MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2019, nic-teaming

I know that Windows server NIC teaming can increase the total bandwidth when used with SMB, and SMB multichannel plays a role in that.

For example, by having 4 x gigabit NICs teamed, you can have 4Gbit transfers with SMB.

However, I would like to know if that would be the case if the server with the NIC teaming is running a MySQL server.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Are you talking about one server and multiple clients or one server and single client?

Comment: One MySQL server with NIC teaming, and multiple clients with NIC teaming as well.

Comment: What is the goal of the teaming?  If it relates to big resultsets for databases, let's talk about ways to reduce the bandwidth needed.